# How do I convert an ascii character 254 in c# to something else?

Tags: c#, .net

I am pulling data from a database that uses ascii character 254 as a delimiter.  I want to replace that with a new line.

I tried this:

```
rec = rec.Replace(char(254), Environment.NewLine);
```

This isn't working though.

Comment: do you mean the ascii character 254? or the "number" 254?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
rec = rec.Replace ('\xFE', '\n');
```

or this:

```
rec = rec.Replace ("\xFE", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Initially I didn't like this answer, but then remembered that the \xFE  should be translated to the right character at compile-time, so it is the cleanest answer. I would stay away from the simple LF character replacement, though, and stick with Environment.NewLine unless you specifically need a literal \x0A character.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your char assignment is wrong:

```
rec = rec.Replace((char)254, Environment.NewLine);
```

just realized there's a type mismatch on that line, too. Here's the code without the mismatch:

```
rec = rec.Replace("" + (char)254, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

Char() is not a constructor for characters. You need to cast a number as a character, there is no equivalent to the VB.NET Chr() function in C#.

Try something like this:

```
rec = rec.Replace( (String) ((char) 254), Environment.NewLine);
```

Edit: String.Replace does not have an overload for (char,string) and NewLine can be multiple characters, so I added another cast to string just to be explicit. (Gonzalo, you caught me during my edit! lol)

Comment: Environment.NewLine is a string and there's no Replace (char, string) overload.

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.NewLine` is a string... you can only replace a char with a char, or a string with a string.

You could try this:

```
rec = rec.Replace("" + (char)254, Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

"" + (char)254 is inelegant. Use "\xFE" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you have won't compile, try this:

```
rec = rec.Replace( ((char)254).ToString(), Environment.NewLine);
```